# How to query adjacent rows in EF?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an app where I am displaying a timeline and I want the calendar event to show up in the middle of the chart. Therefore I would like to also return the previous 10 and next 10 rows in my query. For example let's say I have this table:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | date    | account_balance | action
-------------------------------------------------
.................................................
| 98  |    1   | 6/6/20  | 1524            | null
| 99  |    2   | 6/6/20  | 32              | null
| 100 |    1   | 6/7/20  | 1524            | null
| 101 |    2   | 6/7/20  | 32              | null
| 102 |    1   | 6/8/20  | 1524            | null
| 103 |    2   | 6/9/20  | 32              | null
| 104 |    1   | 6/9/20  | 1524            | null
| 105 |    2   | 6/10/20 | 32              | null
| 106 |    1   | 6/10/20 | 1560            | deposit
| 107 |    2   | 6/11/20 | 32              | null
| 108 |    1   | 6/11/20 | 1560            | null
| 109 |    2   | 6/12/20 | 32              | null
| 110 |    1   | 6/12/20 | 1560            | null
| ...............................................
```

How can I query the latest deposit (`'WHERE action = deposit and user_id = 1'`) and return row 106 as well as ...92,94,96,98,100,102,104 and 108,110,112,114...
Is there a way to achieve this with a single query with EF?

Comment: as there could be many rows with that criteria, you would have to make a loop in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

For your data, and as long there is oly one id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE account (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `date` DATETIME,
>   `account_balance` INTEGER,
>   `action` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO account
>   (`id`, `user_id`, `date`, `account_balance`, `action`)
> VALUES
>   ('98', '1', '6/6/20', '1524', 'null'),
>   ('99', '2', '6/6/20', '32', 'null'),
>   ('100', '1', '6/7/20', '1524', 'null'),
>   ('101', '2', '6/7/20', '32', 'null'),
>   ('102', '1', '6/8/20', '1524', 'null'),
>   ('103', '2', '6/9/20', '32', 'null'),
>   ('104', '1', '6/9/20', '1524', 'null'),
>   ('105', '2', '6/10/20', '32', 'null'),
>   ('106', '1', '6/10/20', '1560', 'deposit'),
>   ('107', '2', '6/11/20', '32', 'null'),
>   ('108', '1', '6/11/20', '1560', 'null'),
>   ('109', '2', '6/12/20', '32', 'null'),
>   ('110', '1', '6/12/20', '1560', 'null');
> ```

> ```
> (SELECT * 
>     FROM account a 
> WHERE id <= (SELECT id FROM account WHERE user_id = 1 AND action = 'deposit' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) 
> AND user_id = 1
> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 11)
> UNION ALL
> (SELECT * 
>     FROM account a 
> WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM account WHERE user_id = 1 AND action = 'deposit' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) 
> AND user_id = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10)
> ORDER BY id;
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | user_id | date                | account_balance | action 
> --: | ------: | :------------------ | --------------: | :------
>  98 |       1 | 0006-06-20 00:00:00 |            1524 | null   
> 100 |       1 | 0006-07-20 00:00:00 |            1524 | null   
> 102 |       1 | 0006-08-20 00:00:00 |            1524 | null   
> 104 |       1 | 0006-09-20 00:00:00 |            1524 | null   
> 106 |       1 | 0006-10-20 00:00:00 |            1560 | deposit
> 108 |       1 | 0006-11-20 00:00:00 |            1560 | null   
> 110 |       1 | 0006-12-20 00:00:00 |            1560 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b317abe4f66b0e8ea0512b8bf114196d)*

With one id this works fine, but with many ids you can use a **stored procedure**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_account_data`(IN _user_id INt, IN _limit INT, IN _action TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _sqltext LONGTEXT;
    DECLARE _selid INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        -- declare cursor for row id
    DEClARE curid 
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT id FROM account WHERE user_id = _user_id AND action = _action;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
        
        SET _sqltext = '';
    OPEN curid;

    getid: LOOP
        FETCH curid INTO _selid;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getid;
        END IF;
        -- build id list
        IF _counter > 0 THEN
            SET _sqltext = CONCAT(_sqltext, " UNION ALL ");
        ELSE
            SET _counter = 1;
         END IF;
            
        SET _sqltext = CONCAT(_sqltext,"(SELECT * FROM account a WHERE id <= ",_selid," AND user_id = ",_user_id," ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ", _limit + 1,")");
        SET _sqltext = CONCAT(_sqltext, " UNION ALL ");
        SET _sqltext = CONCAT(_sqltext,"(SELECT * FROM account a WHERE id > ",_selid," AND user_id = ",_user_id," ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ", _limit ,")");
    END LOOP getid;
    CLOSE curid;        
    SET _sqltext = CONCAT(_sqltext, " ORDER BY id;");
    SET @sql = _sqltext;
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCaTE PREPARE stmt1;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

When you now call this , you get all the rows that have the action for that user and with the 5 rows

```
CALL get_account_data(1,5,'deposit');
```

BUT **caution** the action text should be checked against a whitelist with allowed text, so that **sql injection** can be prevented